# pyspark : fetch common data from dataframe when comparing values of given columns

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have two pyspark dataframes like this. 
data_frame A

```
+----+---+
|name1| id1|
+----+---+
|   a|  3|
|   b|  5|
|   c|  7|
+----+---+
```

data_frame B

```
+----+---+
|name2| id2|
+----+---+
|   a|  13|
|   b|  15|
|   c|  17|
|   d|  6|
|   e|  0|
|   f|  3|
+----+---+
```

I want to fetch dataframe B contents  if values of name1 (from df a)  and name2 (from df b)  matches.  which is as shown below.
o/p dataframe

```
+----+---+
|name2| id2|
+----+---+
|   a|  13|
|   b|  15|
|   c|  17|
+----+---+
```

I want to avoid computationally expensive methods such as collect() etc. 
How this can be done in apache spark?

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df1.join(df2, df1.name1 == df2.name2).select('df2.*')

OR (using sql)

df1.registerTempTable("tableA")
df2.registerTempTable("tableB")

val result = sqlContext.sql("select b.name2, b.id2 from tableA a join tableB b on a.name1=b.name2")

result.show()
+----+----+
|name2| id2|
+----+----+
|   a|  13|
|   b|  15|
|   c|  17|
+----+---+
```